# Can't register Line app on MacBook

Tags: applications, macos

According to the instructions on the website I should be able to got to the Line menu, click on Settings, and the register my email address. Massive problem: Settings is grayed out, non-functional, and masses of searching the internet seem to indicated that no one else is having this problem. Does anyone have an answer? (it will help you to know that I do not yet have a compatible smart phone...)

Comment: is it a must to register from a smart phone?

Comment: Which line app are you trying to register? I saw several when searching to see if this is a unique name for an OS X app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you won't be able to use it, as for using the *Computer Version* you need to have previously registered your email on the *smartphone version*. This is stated on the login screen of the Computer Version.

As a side note, **Settings** is grayed out because you have no account to configure.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that the settings option won't show up until I log in - which requires an account.

Comment: @user122527 Precisely.